# How to implement PrimeNG styleclasses in Angular in order to customize the carousel component?

Tags: html, css, angular, carousel, primeng

I would like to use [PrimeNG's Carousel](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/carousel) component and customize it. How do I implement it into my HTML code?

I have followed some of the advice through Stackoverflow and other websites to help declare the styleclasses thanks to `:host >>> .ui-carousel` on the CSS file. However, I couldn't find a way to use properly on my HTML file.

CSS code

```
    :host >>> .ui-carousel {
      width: 100%;
    }

    :host >>> .ui-carousel-item {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 500px;
      height: 250px;
    }

    :host >>> .ui-carousel-items{
      width: 100%;
    }

    :host >>> .ui-carousel-viewport{
      width: 100%;
    }

    :host >>> .ui-carousel-header{
      background-color: #007aff;
    }
```

HTML code

```
    <p-carousel styleclass="ui-carousel-header" headerText="Items">
    </p-carousel>
    <p-carousel styleclass="ui-carousel-viewport">
      <p-carousel styleclass="ui-carousel-items">
         <p-carousel styleclass="ui-carousel-item" *ngFor="let item of items">
           <img style="height: 100%;" src="{{item.picture}}">
         </p-carousel>
      </p-carousel>
    </p-carousel>
```

What I would like to end up with is only the viewport part of the carousel and hide the header (I have already found a method to do so but haven't applied it yet) and use the navigation buttons elsewhere.
With the code I have here, two headers appear but the viewport isn't filled with the pictures.

Using : Angular 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what are you doing. Why use multi and nested **p-carousel**??? You need to use **ng-template** and set **numVisible="1"** to fit item width 100%

```
<p-carousel headerText="Items" [value]="items" numVisible="1">
    <ng-template let-item pTemplate="item">
        <img style="height: 100%;" [src]="item.picture" >
    </ng-template>
</p-carousel>
```

and CSS normal

```
.ui-carousel {
      width: 100%;
    }

    .ui-carousel-item {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 500px;
      height: 250px;
    }

    .ui-carousel-items{
      width: 100%;
    }

    .ui-carousel-viewport{
      width: 100%;
    }

   .ui-carousel-header{
      background-color: #007aff;
    }
```

Demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1tfeyt)

Comment: Thanks. I just made the problem more complicated in my head I guess... 
I can't use the styleclasses without `:host >>>`

Comment: You can view demo. Only need to style in app.component.css file